# AWS EMR 5 - No Zeppelin Notebook output once adding an artifact

Tags: amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I have a jar file with internal implemetations. I used to upload it to a Zeppelin Notebook using

```
%dep
z.load("/home/hadoop/jar_name.jar")
```

In EMR 5 there is a deprecated error: **Load dependency through GUI interpreter menu instead.**
Once I add the jar path to the artifact section in the interpreter settings, there is no paragraph output for any of the notebooks at all. Paragraphs fail execution and all i see is the **Error** sign to the right of the paragraph.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log files in /var/log/zeppelin?

Comment: The logs are empty..